# can't return an arraylist of objects, coming from a network call

Tags: java, android, arraylist, is-empty

Hi everyone I am a student and I am starting to learn Android. I have a problem with a method, I can't create a method that returns me an ArrayList . After making a network call and adding the users resulting from the network call to the  arrayList, I can't get the method to return the arrayList of all the users downloaded from the network call. My code is:

```
public class Utils {
    static final ArrayList<User>u1 = new ArrayList();
public static  ArrayList<User> getUserPicture(String uid,Activity activity) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
        JSONObject jsonfinal = new JSONObject();
        String url_getProfile = "https://ewserver.helpme/helpme.php";
        try {
            jsonfinal.put("uid", uid);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest
                jsonObjectRequest
                = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                url_getProfile,
                jsonfinal,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String picture=response.getString("picture");
                           u1.add(new User
                                    (uid,picture));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                        }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        MainActivity.requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        return u1;
    }
}
```

Now if i call:

```
ArrayList<User> user=getUserPicture(uid,activity);
Log.d("main_activity_usersize",String.valueOf(user.size()));
```

i get empty arraylists [].Why?how can I return the arraylist  to the method?

Comment: Your `JsonObjectRequest` is evaluated _after_ your method returns. You could either make the method blocking (which would stop all execution on that thread until the value returns), or you can perform the action you wish to take once the `JsonObjectRequest` is evaluated _within_ `onResponse`. This can be made more general by accepting a `Consumer<JsonObject>` in your method, which the `JsonObjectRequest` can call later by passing the object to it. Then callers of your method can `getUserPicture(..., jsonObj -> { /* operate on object */ } );`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)